# What expression is needed for mapping this property?

Tags: automapper

I am trying to map two objects that are *mostly* similar with AutoMapper but one member (AudioSummary) raises the following exception :

*The following property on EchoNestModel.AudioSummary cannot be mapped: AudioSummary*

*Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type EchoNestModel.AudioSummary.*

*Context:*

*- Mapping to property AudioSummary from EchoNest.Api.AudioSummary to EchoNestModel.AudioSummary*

*- Mapping from type EchoNest.Api.TrackProfile to EchoNestModel.Profile*

*Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.*

**Mapping definition**

```
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<TrackProfile, Profile>();
map.ForMember(dest => dest.ForeignIds, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ForeignIdResolver>());
map.ForMember(dest => dest.ForeignReleaseIds, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ForeignReleaseIdResolver>());
map.ForMember(s => s.Media, t => t.Ignore());
map.ForMember(s => s.ProfileId, t => t.Ignore());
map.ForMember(s => s.AudioSummary, t => t.MapFrom(s => s.AudioSummary));
```

I've added the following two lines but a totally different error occurs :

```
map.ForMember(s => s.AudioSummary.Profile, t => t.Ignore());
map.ForMember(s => s.AudioSummary.AudioSummaryId, t => t.Ignore());
```

*Expression 's => s.AudioSummary.Profile' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties.*

*Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.*

*Parameter name: lambdaExpression*

How can I successfully map *AudioSummary* ?

**Source object**

[image]

**Target object**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** In general, try `AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`, this will show you all possible problems in your mapper setup.

From the information you provided, it looks like you need to define map for the AudioSummary classes (dest and source) as well:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MappingTest
    {
        public class SourceAudioSummary
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string OtherData { get; set; }
        }

        public class TrackProfile
        {
            public string Whatever { get; set; }
            public SourceAudioSummary AudioSummary { get; set; }
        }

        public class DestAudioSummary
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string OtherData { get; set; }
        }

        public class Profile
        {
            public string Whatever { get; set; }
            public DestAudioSummary AudioSummary { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Mapping()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<SourceAudioSummary, DestAudioSummary>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<TrackProfile, Profile>();

            var trackProfile = new TrackProfile
                {
                    Whatever = "something",
                    AudioSummary = new SourceAudioSummary
                        {
                            Id = 1,
                            OtherData = "other"
                        }
                };

            var profile = Mapper.Map<TrackProfile, Profile>(trackProfile);

            Assert.That(profile.Whatever == "something");
            Assert.That(profile.AudioSummary.Id == 1);
            Assert.That(profile.AudioSummary.OtherData == "other");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I am getting another error : Value supplied is of type EchoNest.Api.TrackProfile but expected System.String[].
Change the value resolver source type, or redirect the source value supplied to the value resolver using FromMember.

Comment: Actually that is the error message returned by the exception, it didn't make sense to me but now it does, thank you !